# Socket connection not working with no-ip address

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I am having an issue with my socket connection. When I replace my no-ip address with "localhost" it works fine, but as soon as I put in my no-ip address, it cannot connect. I have forwarded the port from my router (port 12345 TCP and UDP forwarded to my local IP address 192.168.1.116). I don't understand why it would work with "localhost" but not with "myaddress.no-ip.org". It was of my understanding all you had to do was forward the port on your router to your local IP address.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your no-ip address by other means? For example accessing your ssh server via that address or something like that? Does that work? Can you ping it?

Comment: @inVader If i attempt to ping the no-ip address, it shows my external IP address so I know the no-ip address is getting to my modem, but that's it.  Edit: added picture of port forwarding.

Comment: A lot of consumer routers won't do this; it won't route a request from an internal NAT'd IP address to the router's external IP address and back in. Test from a machine external to your home network, I suspect you'll find it works.

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking that port, or preventing the Java.exe application from accessing the network?

Comment: Just had  a friend try to connect that lives in Flordia (I live in Ohio).  Same result, tried disabling my anti-virus firewall, and my router firewall.  java is not checked to block the request. not sure what's going on here

Comment: @BrianRoach Would I have to forward the port from my modem to my router?  I have a feeling there is a router built into my modem as there are 4 eithernet ports on the back of my cable modem.  If so, what is the normal ip address for that?

Comment: @Matt - if that's the case and the modem itself is doing NAT, your router is going to have a WAN IP address in the private space (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x, etc). The default gateway for the WAN would be the modem's IP address.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is an internal address. All IP addresses which start with 192.168 are internal addresses. You need to know your *external* address which is what you publish. Then you configure your router to forward your port to your server.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know what my external IP address is, question is, how do I forward that to my internal?  My router only has port numbers, not IP addresses assocaited with it.  Above is a screenshot of my port forwarding page.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to set the same port for internal and external and set the IP address to that of your server.  This means when you connect to external-ip:port it will get passed to internal-ip:port. Your router has one addres on the internet which is your external IP address. You don't need to set it or change it (in fact you can't as its set by your ISP)

Comment: @PeterLawrey How is that any different from what I did?  I think the problem is that the Modem is acting as a router, and I need to tell my ISP to either A. disable the routing feature, or B forward all external ports to 192.168.1.1  Would turning off the NAT on the modem work?  What would the easiest thing to ask for them to do and what specifically do I ask of them?

Comment: If you now try to connect to your external-ip:port what happens?  You should be able to do this regardless of what your ISP does because the connection will go to the router which will pass it back in. (It is possible your router doesn't allow this, so I would try it from another connection if you can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the most probable solution to the problem.  The Modem that I have from Time Warner (RoadRunner) has a built in modem.  I have to get them to bridge the connection so it passes through the router.  My router was looking for something to come in on port 12345 so it could direct it to my computer.  The problem was that TWCs router wasn't forwarding it to my router.  After bridging the connection, it should just pass through the modem to my router.

Comment: If the *WAN* address (not the internal interface's address) of your router is not a routable IP address then it means the Time Warner modem is acting as a router with NAT. In your Cisco router's web interface, what does it list as the WAN address on the status page?

Comment: @BrianRoach I will have to wait until I get home at 4:30 Eastern time to look that up.  I don't have my RD service up and running to check.  I'll let you know sometime after that.

Comment: OK this was the issue, I looked up how to bridge my connection to my router through my modem (essentially turned off DNS on the modem and manually added the NIC address to the modem for forwarding) and now my router sees the external IP address.  After doing that, everything works so this is my selected answer.

Comment: Tre cool - glad you got it figured out. I upvoted your own answer - I figured that was what was going on :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't forward your internal IP address. A 192.168.x.x address is only usable on your internal network. You need to forward you external address. http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Comment: How do I forward my external address? I only have access to my internal router.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question... Im not forwarding my internal IP to no-ip.org, I am forwarding my external.

Comment: Ok. When you try to `telnet` to your external ip and port, what happens?

Comment: Cannot tell from work, the IT admin here has port 23 shut down.

Comment: telnet guildmanager.no-ip.org:12345 returns the error  Could not open connection to the host on port 23: connection failed

Comment: Try `telnet guildmanager.no-ip.org 12345`, note there is no `:`

Comment: Could not open connection to the host on port 12345: connect failed

Comment: This means communication is blocked. either by your firewall at work, at the ISP (unlikely) or by your router.

Comment: I have stated in another answer what I believe is to be the issue.  I will update after I try that.

Comment: You can try connecting to your server using an internet service (it may have to be on port 80)