# Call a self hosted web api from an Android app through a DDNS

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

My client has an account with NoIp. Our goal is to allow an android app call our self hosted Web Api service through the NoIp dynamic ip. I've looked all over for some guidance on this topic, but I haven't found anything remotely related. Everything works in the local environment, android wired to local machine, Visual Studio 2019, using localhost. We've opened ports on the house's router. When I change the outbound ip to that in NoIp, still can't connect. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 1) What do you mean you can't "connect"? Do you have a 4xx error or 5xx error message? 2) Are you able to connect through Postman to that dynamic IP? 
3) Have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413445/11104068
4) Does it work on iOS? Did you give the Android Internet permissions already?

Comment: can you access the server/service in the device's browser?

Comment: there was a second router in the chain that needed ports opened - thanks for answering

Comment: If you have solved this issue , please post your solution to answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to a new house and was unaware that there was a wired internet modem that was connected to a wifi router. Ports had been opened on the router, but not the modem.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accpet your answer, it will help others who have similar issue.